# How to req a page without X-REQUESTED-WITH header in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to extract a page by javascript (client based language) the problem is the third-part remote url doesnt not allow ajax request when i do this req without the header `X-REQUESTED-WITH` it gives the expected data with `200 Success` in response but when i req it with that header it give `403 Forbidden` with no content in respone .

i want to know how to req a page without the header `X-REQUESTED-WITH` in javascript , ajax , jquery or any client based language .

Please help me .
thanks

Comment: one ugly idea might be to let your clients talk with your application, and you do the remote "non-ajax' call yourself. Therefore your application could act as a proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `X-REQUESTED-WITH` header is not "standard". jQuery for instance will add it manually.

So by doing a default XHR request

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( xhr.readyState === 4 ) {
        console.log('done');
    }
};

xhr.open('GET', 'hello=50', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('FOO', 'BAR');
xhr.send(null);
```

there will not be this header. In the above simplified example we added a custom `FOO` request header instead, that is the same thing like jQuery adds the `X-REQUESTED-WITH` header into its ajax requests.